# Why can't I used FUN in lapply when grouping by using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I encountered the following issue with data.table when aggregating, using .SD and specifying lapply with stating the FUN argument from lapply explicitely.
Is this unexpected behaviour or am I just missing something. Why can I not explicitely state FUN in lapply?
The following is a reproducible example.

```
require(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(iris)
dt$Sepal.Length[sample(1:nrow(dt), 10)] <- NA
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(!is.na(x), na.rm=TRUE)), by = Species]
      Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1:     setosa           47          50           50          50
2: versicolor           46          50           50          50
3:  virginica           47          50           50          50
dt[, lapply(.SD, FUN=function(x) sum(!is.na(x), na.rm=TRUE)), by = Species]
Error in ..FUN(FUN = Sepal.Length) : 
  unused argument(s) (FUN = Sepal.Length)
```

---

#### Update:

[**Filed as bug: #4839**](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=4839&group_id=240&atid=975). (Arun's fix now in v1.8.9)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you're missing anything. You should probably file a bug [**here**](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?atid=975&group_id=240&func=browse) linking to this post. Good catch!

This happens because, when you use `lapply` with `.SD` (in `j`), `data.table` tries to find if there's a way to optimise overhead due to function calls if possible. However, in this process, instead of calling the function:

```
..FUN(Sepal.Length)
```

where `..FUN = function(x) sum(!is.na(x), na.rm=TRUE)`, it becomes:

```
..FUN(FUN = Sepal.Length)
```

Since the function has no argument called `FUN` it gives back the error. You can verify this by changing `x` to `FUN` in your function call:

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, FUN=function(FUN) sum(!is.na(FUN), na.rm=TRUE)), by = Species]
#       Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1:     setosa           49          50           50          50
# 2: versicolor           44          50           50          50
# 3:  virginica           47          50           50          50
```

---

Internal: By looking at `[.data.table` function, one way to fix this would be to re-write the line:

```
txt <- as.list(jsub)[-1L]
# [[1]]
# .SD

# $FUN <~~~~ this name FUN gets caught up in building the expression later
# function(x) sum(!is.na(x), na.rm = TRUE)
```

with:

```
txt <- as.list(jsub)[-1L]
names(txt)[2] <- ""
# [[1]]
# .SD

# [[2]]
# function(x) sum(!is.na(x), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Running `CHECK` finished successfully.